# When using pythonRequirements>dockerizePip: true , within codebuild, must I use ecr?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, serverless-framework, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

```
    custom:
       pythonRequirements:
         dockerizePip: true
```

in Python lambda using serverless with dockerizePip , I'm getting this message.
I know dockerizePip uses docker and it works fine in the local. But, when using it via pipeline, the container it uses to build doesn't seem to have 'docker' there.

Or, Maybe it's there but not running?  I get this error message.

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Should I use ECR when I use dockerizePip : true?
Is there a way to not use ECR?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ECR, but `docker` daemon has to be running on the machine. Docker container will be launched to actually build your dependencies with `serverless-python-requirements` plugin. You can also try specifying `dockerizePip: non-linux`, as it might not be needed to dockerize packaging when running on linux machine, but I would advise to test it first on non-prod environment.